# Implementing a timer in java

Tags: java, swing, delay, paint

```
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JLabel;
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.Timer;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;

 class autos extends JLabel
 {
     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
     int z=100,i=50;
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

         JFrame frame=new JFrame("Rectangle");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setSize(1000,1000);
         frame.add(new autos());    
     }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        for(i=1;i<=7;i++)
        {
            g.drawRect(z,100,100,100);
            z=z+120;
            //timer delay
        }

    }
}
```

Hello,I'm trying to create a program in java that draws mre rectangles one after another with a delay(not all of them at once).

Since sleep and `TimeUnit` will freeze the `paintComponent`, I'm a bit clueless.I tried to use a timer to make a delay, but I failed.I cannot understand how to use the timer in this case.

How do I make a time delay between the rectangles?

Comment: *"Since sleep and TimeUnit will freeze the `paintComponent`"* And delay won't?

Comment: You seem to be using a `java.util.Timer`, try a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). See also [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: @user2004685 What do you mean by "delay"?

Comment: @Eliott I do not know how to implement the timer.I don't know how to use the tutorials for my case.I would need some clues.

Comment: You have to think of a Swing Timer as pseudo loop, which, every time it ticks, you update some value which, when your call repaint and your paint method is called, you can update the UI appropriately, of course in this case I might suggest using a BufferedImage and paint to that

Comment: Remember that the first line in a paintComponent method *must* be `super.paintComponent(g);`, or you will see painting artifacts at more-or-less random times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by taking a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

You have to think of a Swing `Timer` as pseudo loop, which, every time it ticks, you update some value which, when your call `repaint` and your `paintComponent` method is called, you can update the UI appropriately

[image: Timer]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int count = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == 7) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    timer.stop();
                    count = 0;
                    timer.start();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension((120 * 7) + 100, 300);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = 100;
            for (int rect = 1; rect <= count; rect++) {
                g2d.drawRect(x, 100, 100, 100);
                x += 120;
                //timer delay
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

ps- Click the panel to get the timer to start

Comment: I do not want to make it start on click,I'm trying to make it start drawing right after the program starts running.

Comment: @DanielTork So? Start it when you want to, I just started it with a mouse click because I can control it and you can see how it works, it's now up to you to fit into your requirements, but, there is the basic idea, demonstratedable and working

Comment: Ok,but I'm getting errors at timer.stop() and timer.start():Cannot refer to the non-final local variable timer defined in an enclosing scope

Comment: What version of Java are you using? 6?  You could make `timer` an instance field or mark it as final, `final Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {` depending on your needs

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a for loop to do this job.You can use a swing Timer like this:

```
int delay=500;// delay time in ms
Timer t=new Timer(delay,new ActionListener() {

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
         autos.this.getGraphics().drawRect(z,100,100,100); // draw rectangle in your panel's graphics
         repaint(); // this line calls paint component to show changes
         i++;
         z+=120;
         if (i>70) t.stop(); // for loop's condition
     }
 });
```

Comment: Doing autos.this.getGraphics().drawRect(z,100,100,100); followed by repaint will clear the UI at best, at worst, it will make it flash. You should NEVER call getGraphics, it's not how custom painting works

Comment: I should place this in paintComponent,no?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Then where?

Comment: @DanielTork Any where (but the paint methods), the constructor maybe. Paint can be called for any number of reasons, sometimes in quick succession, paint should be used for painting and nothing else