# Refreshing JFrame after invoking method through Reflections

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I have buttons that add strings with method names to the commands ArrayList. When a certain other (play) button is pressed, I want all the commands to be run. My current problem is that after clicking the play button, you can only see the end state after all the commands have been run. I would like to see the intermediate states - the state of the JFrame after each individual command has been run. All the methods call frame.repaint() and frame.revalidate(). I tried adding Thread.sleep in the loop, but it did not work.

```
playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          try {
            for (String s : commands) {
              Method m = Robot.class.getMethod(s);
              m.invoke(null);
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Start by doing some research into Concurrency in Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer I've done some programming using SwingWorker in the past - is that what is needed here? Or do you mean how the event dispatch thread works?

Comment: Yes (or a Swing Timer) and yes - The ui won’t be updated until after the actionPerformed method returns, as it’s called on the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer i think i kind of understand - do you mind posted a slightly more detailed explanation as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515620/implementing-a-timer-in-java/36516160#36516160) and [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). You should start by writing small sample programs to get a better understanding of how they work and how you might be able to achieve what you want

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry for so many questions - but would it work to have the actionperformed method call a method that starts a swingworker/timer to execute the animations?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i just got it. What i did was run a thread in the background checks to see if the button was clicked, and animates after the button is clicked

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe, any interactions with the UI should be done from within the context of the EDT. You should use the `ActionListener` to determinations when the button is clicked and either a Swing `Timer` or `SwingWorker` to perform each step